# get timezone abbreviation based on timezone id

Tags: php, timezone

I want to get the timezone abbreviation based on timezone name.for example, if the timezone name is America/New_york then in return I want to get the abbreviation as EST.Is there any solution available for it? I need the procedural style solution for it.Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
function getabbreviatedtimezone($location){
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone($location));
return $date->format('T');
}
echo "The Time Zone corresponding to 'America/New York' is ".getabbreviatedtimezone('America/New_York');
?>
```

should do that.

Comment: Is there any procedural method for this solution??

Comment: @EvilsEmpire  see the updated answer.

Comment: @EvilsEmpire  pease accept the answer if it helped